# Is there a way to make these 3 queries into one

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have this code which is really not the prettiest and the most efficient. The code works but i feel like there is way to avoid all the looping and combine these queries and make possibly one array. I was just wondering if anyone had any pointers on how to improve this

```
$sql = "SELECT p.image, group_concat(pi.image) as additional_images 
FROM product as p 
JOIN product_image as pi on pi.product_id=p.product_id 
WHERE p.product_id = '{$product['standard']['product_id']}'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$images_before = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$images = array();
if($images_before['additional_images'] != ""){
$images = explode(",", $images_before['additional_images']);
}
array_push($images, $images_before['image']);
$sql2 = "SELECT p.image, group_concat(pi.image) as additional_images 
FROM product as p 
JOIN product_image as pi on pi.product_id=p.product_id 
WHERE p.product_id = '{$product['professional']['product_id']}'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
$images_before2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
$images2 = array();
if($images_before2['additional_images'] != ""){
$images2 = explode(",", $images_before2['additional_images']);
}
array_push($images2, $images_before2['image']);
$sql3 = "SELECT p.image, group_concat(pi.image) as additional_images 
FROM product as p 
JOIN product_image as pi on pi.product_id=p.product_id 
WHERE p.product_id = '{$product['premium']['product_id']}'";
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
$images_before3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3);
$images3 = array();
if($images_before3['additional_images'] != ""){
$images3 = explode(",", $images_before3['additional_images']);
}
array_push($images3, $images_before3['image']);
$counter = 0;
foreach($images as $image) {
      if ($counter == 0) {
          echo "<a id='show_{$product['standard']['product_id']}' style='display:none;' href='http://somesite.com/shop_possystems/image/{$image}' rel='prettyPhoto[show_{$product['standard']['product_id']}]'></a>";
                $counter++;
      }else{
        echo "<a style='display:none;' href='http://somesite.com/shop_possystems/image/{$image}' rel='prettyPhoto[show_{$product['standard']['product_id']}]'></a>";
            $counter++;
        }
}

$counter2 = 0;
  foreach($images2 as $image) {
        if ($counter2 == 0) {
            echo "<a id='show_{$product['professional']['product_id']}' style='display:none;' href='http://somesite.com/shop_possystems/image/{$image}' rel='prettyPhoto[show_{$product['professional']['product_id']}]'></a>";
                    $counter2++;
        }else{
          echo "<a style='display:none;' href='http://somesite.com/shop_possystems/image/{$image}' rel='prettyPhoto[show_{$product['professional']['product_id']}]'></a>";
                $counter2++;
            }
}
$counter3 = 0;
    foreach($images3 as $image) {
          if ($counter3 == 0) {
              echo "<a id='show_{$product['premium']['product_id']}' style='display:none;' href='http://somesite.com/shop_possystems/image/{$image}' rel='prettyPhoto[show_{$product['premium']['product_id']}]'></a>";
                        $counter3++;
          }else{
            echo "<a style='display:none;' href='http://somesite.com/shop_possystems/image/{$image}' rel='prettyPhoto[show_{$product['premium']['product_id']}]'></a>";
                    $counter3++;
                }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I've pasted code into the question body, if you don't mind.

Comment: That code makes my eyes bleed :)

Comment: makes mine bleed too...thats why i posted the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `where p.product_id = <value>`, use `WHERE IN` syntax:

```
$sql = "SELECT  ...
WHERE p.product_id IN (
  {$product['standard']['product_id']},
  {$product['professional']['product_id']}, 
  {$product['premium']['product_id']}
)";
```

Comment: That seems like a better way but how do i know which how to differentiate  standard, professional, and premium

Comment: @Tamer Presumably by selecting an additional column from the image table, telling you which kind of images it is. If this column doesn't exist, your data is badly laid out and, as Silver Light's answer states, you should consider a slight redesign.

Answer (score 1):

You code is very bad by itself. You need to study application architecture and design along with the language itself.

Here is a very good article to start: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html

As for the tips on code:

Don't use `group_concat` and the `explode`. Better to do two queries without `JOIN`:

1. get all the images using IN()
2. get all the additional_images using IN()
3. loop over additional_images and bind them to images in PHP loop

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "
    SELECT p.product_id, p.image, group_concat(pi.image) as additional_images 
    FROM product as p 
        JOIN product_image as pi on pi.product_id=p.product_id 
    WHERE p.product_id IN ({$product['standard']['product_id']}, {$product['professional']['product_id']}, {$product['premium']['product_id']})";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($product_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $images = explode(',', $product_result['additional_images']);
    $first = true;
    foreach($images as $image) {
        if($first) {
            echo "<a id='show_{$product_result['product_id']}' style='display:none;' href='http://posnation.com/shop_possystems/image/{$image}' rel='prettyPhoto[show_{$product_result['product_id']}]'></a>";
            $first = false;
        }
        else {
            echo "<a style='display:none;' href='http://posnation.com/shop_possystems/image/{$image}' rel='prettyPhoto[show_{$product['standard']['product_id']}]'></a>";
        }
    }
}
```